# NodeJS - Path and Request Module | How do I rename multiple duplicates?

Tags: node.js, path, request, filesystems

I'm currently using Request, File System and Path to basically download 100+ images from URLs and store it into the local directory. I'm using Path to rename any files that is found to be existing on the local directory.

My code looks like this

```
var download = function (url, dest, cb) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest, {flags: 'wx'});
  var sendReq = request.get(url);

  //There's a bunch more code here but I removed it for the sake of relevance

  file.on('error', function (err) { // Handle errors
    if (err.code === "EEXIST") { //if image already exist, create new images with same name but numbers

        let newFileNames = path.parse(dest);

        for (let p = 1; p <= 5; p+=1) {
            newFileNames.name += '(' + (p) + ')';
            newFileNames.base = newFileNames.name + newFileNames.ext;
            return download(url, path.format(newFileNames), cb);

        }
    } 
    return cb(err.message);
  });
};
```

I'm calling the download variable through a for loop every 30 seconds (just for testing) and if I'm using the flags: 'wx', it won't overwrite any existing files when it's downloading.

What I want to achieve is the files looking like this

```
First download:    imageA    | imageB    | imageC    | imageD    |
Second download:   imageA(1) | imageB(1) | imageC(1) | imageD(1) |
Third download:    imageA(2) | imageB(2) | imageC(2) | imageD(2) |
Fourth download:   imageA(3) | imageB(3) | imageC(3) | imageD(3) |
Fifth download:    imageA(4) | imageB(4) | imageC(4) | imageD(4) |
```

But what is happening is my files end up looking like this

```
First download:    imageA             | imageB             | imageC             | imageD             |
Second download:   imageA(1)          | imageB(1)          | imageC(1)          | imageD(1)          |
Third download:    imageA(1)(1)       | imageB(1)(1)       | imageC(1)(1)       | imageD(1)(1)       |
Fourth download:   imageA(1)(1)(1)    | imageB(1)(1)(1)    | imageC(1)(1)(1)    | imageD(1)(1)(1)    |
Fifth download:    imageA(1)(1)(1)(1) | imageB(1)(1)(1)(1) | imageC(1)(1)(1)(1) | imageD(1)(1)(1)(1) |
```

I'm fairly certain this has to do with the return in my for loop because if I move that outside of the for loop, my requested files looks like this

```
First download:    imageA                 | imageB                | imageC                | imageD                |
Second download:    imageA(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) | imageB(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) | imageC(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) | imageD(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) |
```

Which isn't what I want as well. Also note that I only want to download 5 copies of the same image (the image is updated through the url which is why I want to keep several copies, the image has timestamps on them). Sorry for the long post.

**EDIT 1**

Well I got it to work now but I wouldn't consider this method efficient, lul

```
 file.on('error', function (err) { // Handle errors
    if (err.code === "EEXIST") { //if image already exist, create new images with same name but numbers


        dest = dest.slice(0, dest.length -4);
        var newFileNames = path.parse(dest);
        console.log(dest);

        if (dest.endsWith('(1)')) {
            dest = dest.slice(0, -3);
            newFileNames = path.parse(dest);
            newFileNames.name += '(2).jpg';
          } else {
            newFileNames.name += '(1).jpg';
        }
        newFileNames.base = newFileNames.name + newFileNames.ext;
    } else {
        fs.unlink(dest, function () { // Delete the file async. )
            file.close(cb);
        });
    }
    return cb(err.message);
});
```

What it does it checks if the filename ends with (1) in the filename (excluding file extension), if it does then remove (1) and replace it with (2). Otherwise, if it does not contain (1) then add (1) to the end of the filename.

It works the way I intended it to but if there's a more efficient method, your input will be greatly appreicated. I'm still new to this and want to learn as much as I can.

**EDIT 2** Nevermind, I have solved the issue.